# How to filter a function output by using a function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to implement a function that takes the output from another function as one argument, a year value (as int) and outputs enrolment data for the year given to the function. If the enrolment data has multiple entries for the same year (e.g., February and August), a mean value for the enrolment numbers in each year must be computed (this can be non-int).

The data the function takes as the first argument is a list of tuples. This is an example:

```
Original data = [
    ('2009-02-01', 'Ainslie School', 6, 46),
    ('2009-02-01', 'Ainslie School', 0, 65),
    ('2009-02-01', 'Ainslie School', 0, 49),
    ('2009-02-01', 'Ainslie School', 1, 44),
    ('2009-02-01', 'Ainslie School', 4, 57),
    ('2009-02-01', 'Ainslie School', 3, 64)
    ]
```

- First tuple element: date (str)
- Second tuple element: School name (str)
- Third element: year level (int)
- Fourth element: enrolment number (int)

I've tried using a list comprehension to filter out the date and only include those things that match the year argument passed to the function call.

Example:

```
target_year = '2019'
enrolment_data = # Output from the first function, i.e. list of 4-item tuples.
```

This is the list comprehension I'm trying to use to filter tuples by year:

```
result = [result_tuple[1:4] for result_tuple in enrolmen_data if (result_tuple[0][0:4] == target_year)]

print("Data: " + str(result))
Out >>> [('Ainslie School', 6, 46), ('Ainslie School', 0, 65), ('Ainslie School', 0, 49), ('Ainslie School', 1, 44)]
```

This is the function code:

```
def get_yearly_enrolment(enrolment, year, levels=[]):
    """Takes enrolment data (returned by the read_enrolment_data function)
    and returns a dictionary with keys being school names, and values being
    the enrolment numbers for the year of census totalled over year levels
    given by levels; if the census year has multiple data (eg, for
    February and August), a mean value of enrolment numbers for that year is used.
    """

    enrolment = read_enrolment_data('Census_Data_for_all_ACT_Schools.csv')
    enrol_data = [result_tuple[1:4] for result_tuple in enrolment if (result_tuple[0][0:4] == year)]

    result_dict = {}
    for line in enrol_data:
        key = line[0]
        enrolment_number_value = line[2]
        result_dict[key] = enrolment_number_value
    return result_dict
```

The expected output of the new function is to return a dictionary with keys being school names, and values being the enrolment numbers for the year passed to the function. If the census year has multiple data (e.g., for February and August), a mean value of enrolment numbers for that year is used.

The only output I'm seeing when I call the new function is a KeyError.

```
def test_get_yearly_enrolment():
        schools = [
            ('2009-01-01', 'Ainslie School',  1,  46),
            ('2015-01-01', 'Ainslie School',  1,  52),
            ('2011-01-01', 'Amaroo School',  6, 116),
            ('2011-01-01', 'Aranda Primary School',  3,  57),
            ('2013-01-01', 'Bonython Primary School',  3,  47),
            ('2014-01-01', 'Mount Stromlo High School', 10, 176),
            ('2011-01-01', 'Yarralumla Primary School',  2,  31)
        ]

        res = get_yearly_enrolment(schools, 2011, [2,3])
>       assert res['Aranda Primary School'] == 57.0
E       KeyError: 'Aranda Primary School'
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happens.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: You need to make a [mre] or at bare minimum include the full error message with traceback.

Comment: The `enrolment` parameter to `get_yearly_enrolment()` is useless, because you're overwriting that variable inside the function.  Also, why does that function bother defining `enrol_data` when that variable isn't used?

Comment: @John Gordon cheers, I've fixed that. Hope the updated version assists.

Comment: You're passing `year` as an integer to `get_yearly_enrolment()`, but the way the function is using it, it expects it to be a string.  Integer `2011` is not the same as string `"2011"`.